How do I insert ILP data into a non-WAL table in QuestDB?
I started using QuestDB and tried to use the ILP client to send data. I made a table like this:
CREATE TABLE 'trades' (
  symbol SYMBOL,
  side SYMBOL,
  price DOUBLE,
  amount DOUBLE,
  timestamp TIMESTAMP
) timestamp (timestamp) PARTITION BY NONE BYPASS WAL;

I send using the Python client like this:
from questdb.ingress import Sender, TimestampNanos

conf = f'http::addr=localhost:9000;'
with Sender.from_conf(conf) as sender:
    sender.row(
        'trades',
        symbols={'symbol': 'ETH-USD', 'side': 'sell'},
        columns={'price': 2615.54, 'amount': 0.00044},
        at=TimestampNanos.now())
    sender.flush()

But when I send it, I get an error saying that I can't insert data into a non-WAL table. How can I resolve this?

By default, the ILP clients use HTTP transport to send your data to QuestDB. The ILP/HTTP connector is only compatible with WAL tables. If you wish to send data to a non-WAL table, you should use ILP/TCP, which can be configured with a simple change to the configuration string:
conf = f'tcp::addr=localhost:9009;'

In most cases, WAL tables should be preferred, as they support concurrent ingestion from multiple protocols, and better handling of out-of-order data.
Furthermore, using HTTP transport for your ILP submissions provides transactionality and error handling, making it easier to send data and guarantee idempotency. With TCP transport, its possible to have partial writes, or disconnects without a useful client-side error.
If you are having a problem with WAL tables, you should contact QuestDB Support for help!

I have come across the same problem, I think the only way was to use PostgreSQL wire protocol. But if the flag pg.security.readonly is set to true, you will need to change it. You will also need to run it in a retry/backoff loop to avoid the table busy [reason=insert] error.
